# Как назначить переменную из прототипа

Tags: javascript, ооп

Как изменить значение прототипа из другой функции? Мой код к сожалению не работает(

```
behaviorProto.Instance = function(type, inst)
{
    this.inst = inst;               
};
var behinstProto = behaviorProto.Instance.prototype;

function Acts() {};

Acts.prototype.GreedStartMoving = function ()
{
    behinstProto.inst.x = 110; //Не работает
    behinstProto.inst.y = 110; //Не работает
};
```

Comment: Зачем? Опишите ситуацию, когда это необходимо

Comment: что именно не работает? выдает ошибку? ничего не происходит? не меняется значение в ожидаемом месте?

Answer (score 1):

Динамическое изменение свойств прототипа.

**Правильно**

Создаем объект прототипа со свойствами, к примеру.

```
var someFunction = function() { } 
someFunction.prototype.some = "a";
somePrototype = someFunction.prototype;
```

Динамически меняем свойства прототипа.

```
function changeSomeProto() {
  somePrototype.some = "b"
}
```

**Не правильно**

Создаем свойства экземпляра класса!

```
var someFunction = function() {
  this.some = 'a'; // Это собственное свойство, а не свойство прототипа
}
var somePrototype = someFunction.prototype;
```

Пытаемся менять свойства экземпляра класса через прототип, что не возможно.

```
function changeSomeProto() {
  somePrototype.some = "b"; // Мы присваиваем значение не существующему свойству прототипа
}
```

Comment: а почему не рекомендуете?

Comment: чем ваш код отличается от приведенного в вопросе?

Comment: Мой код отличается, от приведенного в вопросе, созданием прототипа.

Comment: но прототип по умолчанию пустой объекта, в чем смысле его в данном случае отдельно создавать? только ради установки поля конструктор?

Comment: Поле конструктор всегда создает по умолчанию. Я лишь продемонстрировал то, как можно перезаписать прототип функции. Ладно я сейчас перепишу пост, что бы было понятней.

Answer (score 0):

В данном коде вы создаете конструктор

```
behaviorProto.Instance = function(type, inst)
{
    this.inst = inst;               
};
```

сохраняете ссылку на прототип

```
var behinstProto = behaviorProto.Instance.prototype;
```

Создаете второй конструктор

```
function Acts() {};

Acts.prototype.GreedStartMoving = function ()
{
    behinstProto.inst.x = 110; //пытаетесь изменить объект в сохраненном прототипе
    behinstProto.inst.y = 110; 
};
```

Ошибка заключается в том, что в прототипе **нет** данного свойства.
Вы его добавляете напрямую в создаваемый объект в этой строчке: `this.inst = inst;`

Соответственно, когда вы пытаетесь изменить свойства этого объекта в прототипе, вы скорее всего получаете ошибку.

Если вы хотите, чтобы после изменения значения в прототипе, поменялось значение во **всех** объектах, тогда нужно либо:

- хранить свойство не в объекте, а в прототипе

  ```
  this.inst = inst; //убрать эту строчку

  behinstProto.inst = {}; //добавить нужное свойство в прототип.
  ```
- хранить все созданные объекты, и при изменении этого свойства - пробегаться по ним и выставлять новое значение, каждому объекту.